# Hazelcast | unable to connect Hazelcast cluster to mancenter

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have 5 different apps which is creating Hazelcast instance programmatic, below is my code-

```
Config config = new XmlConfigBuilder().build();
config.getGroupConfig().setName("dev");
config.getGroupConfig().setPassword(password);
config.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true);
config.getManagementCenterConfig().setUrl("http://localhost:8081/mancenter");
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember("localhost");
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance=Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

And on deploying all 5 application we are getting cluster like this in console-

```
Members [5] {
        Member [localhost]:5701 - df32e05a-38f1-4cb4-80dc-94756061e86e
        Member [localhost]:5702 - d82becbb-b1d2-498a-a043-c6b9a9239636 this
        Member [localhost]:5703 - df32e05a-5h8h-4lg8-k0h0-91156061e45e
        Member [localhost]:5704 - d82becbb-t4t6-jf79-lf80-c4m9a9239296
        Member [localhost]:5705 - df32e05a-454d-t7j0-d670-93l56061e89e
}
```

I have deployed mancenter jar on port 8081 using following command-

```
java -jar ~/hazelcast/hazelcast-mancenter-3.12.5.war 8081 hazelcast-mancenter
```

Though I am not able to find any of the connected client/member on mancenter. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Below are the log exception-

```
[hz._hzInstance_1_dev.MC.State.Sender] com.hazelcast.internal.management.ManagementCenterService - [localhost]:5702 [dev] [3.7.5] Exception occurred while calculating stats
 {} java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: localhost
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:607) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:446) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
```

Hazelcast dependency in build.gradle-

```
compile('com.hazelcast:hazelcast:3.7.5')
compile('com.hazelcast:hazelcast-client:3.7.5')
```

Note there is no hazelcast server is running on my machine, member/client is only being created programmatic.

Comment: Can you try with the following config?
config.getManagementCenterConfig().setUrl("http://localhost:8081/hazelcast-mancenter");

You can also verify from hazelcast logs if Management Center connection is established. 

Additionally, you can't use MC 3.12 with hazelcast 3.7.5. MC 3.12 supports only hazelcast 3.12.x or 3.11.x

Comment: [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.MC.State.Sender] com.hazelcast.internal.management.ManagementCenterService - [localhost]:5702 [dev] [3.7.5] Exception occurred while calculating stats
 {} java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: localhost
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:607) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:446) ~[?:1.8.0_222]

Answer (score 0):

There was version incompatibly with mancenter & Hazelcast. Used both of 3.7.5 version.